# Can I create a background service on iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, location

I am developing an iphone app. the iphone which install my app was asked to upload it's location every minute(or hour) to a webservice. So what should i do with this situation?

I know there is a corelocation framework,  I could use it for my app. like when I run this app, the corelocation will grab the GPS for my. my question is what if I close the app? Can i still get the GPS and upload it to webservice every minute? If I can't,  how could I ?

Comment: Could you please revise the title to match the question? I was searching for "Add location provider on ios" and got this unrelated question.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenient. The title is just updated.

Answer (score 1):

You could enable background location service, If application is in background and receives a considerable change in location it will activate the app for a brief amount of time, This will give you some time to process. Apple recommends not to use web-service calls during this time, because there wont be any guarantee that the app would be live when it returns back. But since you just want to update the location, you could just post it and dont have to wait for response. Please note that significant location change should be used and this will help you to save your device's battery life. This is when the app is in background state.

May be you could try registering for the proximity/location alert or something. But i am not sure whether it would help when app is closed.

Comment: How could I enable background location service? Is there any way that I can create a startup service to upload the GPS all the time? like windows service, once you turn on the pc, it's running all the time until pc is shut down

Comment: please refer  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20

Answer (score 0):

If your app is running in the background then you can get the GPS data but it the application is removed from the Background then you cannot get the GPS data. This is not possible in iPhone.